# PHP & MySQL - Deleting table rows problem

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

Okay my script is supposed to delete a specific users case which is stored in 2 MySQL tables but for some reason when the user deletes the specific case it deletes all the users cases I only want it to delete the case the user selects. I was wondering how can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance for helping.

Here is the PHP & MySQL code.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_case'])) {

$cases_ids = array();

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT cases.*, users_cases.* FROM cases INNER JOIN users_cases ON users_cases.cases_id = cases.id WHERE users_cases.user_id='$user_id'");

if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
}  else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
        $cases_ids[] = $row["cases_id"];
    }
}

foreach($_POST['delete_id'] as $di) {
    if(in_array($di, $cases_ids)) {
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM users_cases WHERE cases_id = '$di'");

        $dbc2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM cases WHERE id = '$di'");
    }

}

}
```

Here is the XHTML code.

```
<li>
<input type="text" name="file[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="case[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" size="25" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_case" id="delete_case" value="Delete Case" />
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" />
</li>

<li>
<input type="text" name="file[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="case[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" size="25" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_case" id="delete_case" value="Delete Case" />
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" /> 
</li>

<li>
<input type="text" name="file[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="case[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" size="25" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_case" id="delete_case" value="Delete Case" />
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" /> 
</li>
```

Here is the MySQL tables.

```
CREATE TABLE cases (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
file VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
case VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE users_cases (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cases_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? What are values of all variables, queries?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Yes I tried debugging the code but with no success.

Comment: This may be because the id of all the cases is being passed even when the user selects one case....

Comment: how do I fix this problem so that only the specific case sends the id?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734688/php-mysql-deleting-multiple-rows-script-problem

Comment: "but with no success."
 with no success what? printing variables and queries contents? try again.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, you seem to have an attitude and are blind the other question was on how I can delete, this problem is I'm deleting all the users cases.

Answer (score 1):

From first glance it's probably because all that HTML is contained in the same form. So, no matter which **Delete Case** button you click, every one of the **delete_id[]** hidden fields is going to be submitted to the server.

So you'd need to separate each row into it's own form like...

```
<li>
<form method="POST" action="someURL.php">
<input type="text" name="file[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="case[]" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" size="25" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_case" id="delete_case" value="Delete Case" />
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" />
</form>
</li>
```

or something else like changing the *Submit* buttons to just plain *Button* and adding some javascript...

Comment: Another alternative would be that you keep one form, with one single Delete Case button and checkboxes, so the user can check the cases he wants to remove (ie. replace `<input type="hidden" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" />` with `<input type="checkbox" name="delete_id[]" value="' . $row['cases_id'] . '" />`

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the id of all the cases is being passed even when the user selects one case....

The following may work to get only the values selected by the user...

1. Associate a check box with each li with an unique id
2. Let the user select the check box of the cases he wants to delete
3. When the user presses 'Delete' or something, use javascript to collect id of the cases for which the check box is checked...
4. Then submit these ids to the next page....